# Consistently Encrypt a String

Tags: c#, cryptography

I have a C# console app. In this app, I'm trying to accept 1) A string and 2) A key. The key will be used to encrypt the string. I'm basing my implementation on the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged?view=net-5.0#examples). At this time, my code looks like this:

```
var input = "This is a test"
var key = "ffb1cb7a-341b-1529-bc52-5d278fb7f18d"

var encrypted = EncryptString(input, key);
Console.WriteLine(encrypted);

...

private string EncryptString(string input, string key)
{
  byte[] result;
  using (var aes = new AesManaged())
  {
    aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey);
    aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
      ICryptoTransform transform = encryptionAlgorithm.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
      using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
      {
        using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream))
        {
          streamWriter.Write(s);
        }
        result = memoryStream.ToArray();
      }
    }
  }
  return Convert.ToBase64String(result);
}
```

I've intentionally hard-coded the `input` and `key` value for testing purposes. I've noticed that the `result` (displayed via the `encrypted` variable) is different every time. If I enter the same string and key, I would expected the same value. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You haven't set an IV, so I believe one is being generated for you randomly. If you set *that* consistently as well, I'd expect for you to get the same results.

Comment: There are even some problems with variable names: `secretKey` vs `key`, `encryptionAlgorithm` probably defined outside the method.

Comment: You should keep in mind that a **non determistic** encryption result is better than a ciphertext that looks like the same each time the encryption runs.  C# is adding a random iv because a static iv will break your encryption.